# Access denied when uninstalling matplotlib with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I want to uninstall matplotlib library with pip

```
$pip uninstall matplotlib
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python38\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\' -> 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\~atplotlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 98, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 642, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 373, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 271, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 311, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 809, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 740, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 618, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\work\lib\shutil.py", line 616, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python38\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\backends\\_backend_agg.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
```

I have no idea how to solve that, I want to install another version of matplotlib, and because of that I must uninstall matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a working environment (or virtual env) and install all the libraries and dependencies there. It seems that you are trying to install it locally and it's not a good practice, sometimes you will find errors between different versions of packages.

It seems that you don't have permission to install any packages where python is.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python38\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\' -> 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\~atplotlib'
```

Go to the directory (`c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\python`) and give admin permission to your user (or 'sudo')

Comment: I am in an working env, I am not on base. I am on windows, I don't have sudo. And that file already has admin permission.

Comment: are you working in an anaconda environment? why are you trying to install it through pip?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in anaconda, I'm using pip because PIP is a package manager and it should work. I know that I could use conda but that is another topic that does not solve this question.

Comment: when you work in a conda enviroment it's recommended to install all the packages through conda channels and not pip

Comment: Conda lacks support, it is more stable but it does not have access to all the packages from pip. That's why people use pip. But again, this is outside the topic of this question.